# Why does Perl think 1<<-1 is 9223372036854775808?

Tags: perl, bit-shift

If I understand [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Shift-Operators) correctly, this operation should something undefined:

> The result of overflowing the range of the integers is undefined because it is undefined also in C. In other words, using 32-bit integers, `1 << 32` is undefined. **Shifting by a negative number of bits is also undefined**.

---

I'm noticing two things on my setup that I cannot explain:

1. `1 << -1` returns `9223372036854775808` without `bigint` or `integer` pragmas (returns `NaN` when they are active).

   ```
   > perl -le "print 1<<-1"
     9223372036854775808
   ```
2. `1 << -1` returns true when tested with `defined`, regardless of whether or not the `bigint` or `integer` pragmas are in effect

   ```
   > perl -le "print 'yes' if defined(1<<-1)"
     yes

   > perl -le "use integer; print 'yes' if defined(1<<-1)"
     yes

   > perl -le "use bigint; print 'yes' if defined(1<<-1)"
     yes
   ```

---

**Details of my setup**:

```
> perl -V
Set up gcc environment - gcc.exe (rubenvb-4.5.4) 4.5.4
Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 16 subversion 3) configuration:

  Platform:
    osname=MSWin32, osvers=5.2, archname=MSWin32-x64-multi-thread
    uname=''
    config_args='undef'
    hint=recommended, useposix=true, d_sigaction=undef
    useithreads=define, usemultiplicity=define
    useperlio=define, d_sfio=undef, uselargefiles=define, usesocks=undef
    use64bitint=define, use64bitall=undef, uselongdouble=undef
    usemymalloc=n, bincompat5005=undef
  Compiler:
    cc='C:\Perl64\site\bin\gcc.exe', ccflags ='-DNDEBUG -DWIN32 -D_CONSOLE -DNO_STRICT -DWIN64 -DCONSERVATIVE -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DUSE_SITECUSTOMIZE -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DUSE_PERLIO -DHASATTRIBUTE -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields',
    optimize='-O2',
    cppflags='-DWIN32'
    ccversion='', gccversion='gcc.exe (rubenvb-4.5.4) 4.5.4', gccosandvers=''
    intsize=4, longsize=4, ptrsize=8, doublesize=8, byteorder=12345678
    d_longlong=undef, longlongsize=8, d_longdbl=define, longdblsize=8
    ivtype='__int64', ivsize=8, nvtype='double', nvsize=8, Off_t='__int64', lseeksize=8
    alignbytes=8, prototype=define
  Linker and Libraries:
    ld='C:\Perl64\site\bin\g++.exe', ldflags ='-L"C:\Perl64\lib\CORE"'
    libpth=\lib
    libs=-lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -lnetapi32 -luuid -lws2_32 -lmpr -lwinmm -lversion -lodbc32 -lodbccp32 -lcomctl32 -lmsvcrt
    perllibs=-lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -lnetapi32 -luuid -lws2_32 -lmpr -lwinmm -lversion -lodbc32 -lodbccp32 -lcomctl32 -lmsvcrt
    libc=msvcrt.lib, so=dll, useshrplib=true, libperl=perl516.lib
    gnulibc_version=''
  Dynamic Linking:
    dlsrc=dl_win32.xs, dlext=dll, d_dlsymun=undef, ccdlflags=' '
    cccdlflags=' ', lddlflags='-mdll -L"C:\Perl64\lib\CORE"'


Characteristics of this binary (from libperl): 
  Compile-time options: HAS_TIMES HAVE_INTERP_INTERN MULTIPLICITY
                        PERLIO_LAYERS PERL_DONT_CREATE_GVSV
                        PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT PERL_IMPLICIT_SYS
                        PERL_MALLOC_WRAP PERL_PRESERVE_IVUV PL_OP_SLAB_ALLOC
                        USE_64_BIT_INT USE_ITHREADS USE_LARGE_FILES
                        USE_LOCALE USE_LOCALE_COLLATE USE_LOCALE_CTYPE
                        USE_LOCALE_NUMERIC USE_PERLIO USE_PERL_ATOF
                        USE_SITECUSTOMIZE
  Locally applied patches:
    ActivePerl Build 1603 [296746]
  Built under MSWin32
  Compiled at Mar 13 2013 13:31:10
  @INC:
    C:/Perl64/site/lib
    C:/Perl64/lib
    .
```

Comment: It means "undefined" as in "undefined behaviour".

Comment: Your C compiler probably extracts the lower 6 bits of the shift input since it expects a 6-bit input (a number from 0 to 63). `1 << (-1 & 0x3F) == 1 << 63 == 9223372036854775808`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When they say undefined, they are referring to [*undefined behaviour*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), not the value `undef`.

If the result of an operation is undefined behaviour, it means that anything could happen -- you could get a surprising result, a different result on different platforms, a different result each time you do the same thing, or 3-foot tall snails could come out of your computer and start speaking Swahili (though that last one is rather uncommon in practice).

In other words, because it's explicitly documented as undefined behaviour, *anything* perl does is technically correct -- which means you can't rely on it to do anything useful.

Answer (score 4):

The number 9223372036854775808 is equal to 2^63. Given a 64-bit unsigned integer initialized to 1, rotating it by one bit to the right gives this result. This is probably what's happening: << -1 is being interpreted as a rotate right by one.

But since shifting by negative values is undefined, this is not something that can be depended on. The coincidence is worth noting, however.